# Hide the search box in Windows 7 Explorer but not in the Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search

Using Windows 7 I want to hide the search box in Explorer but not in the Start Menu.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can resize it but thats all that you can do

Go to the space between the the address bar and the search bar to resize

Or you can disable both explorer and start menu by following [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10246/how-to-disable-search-in-windows-7/) (Though i understand that this isn't what you really want)

Comment: You should of just started the answer with, "No it is not possible!" I think it is possible, but it takes some serious code that would likely be unstable.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the freeware [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/).  There are two parts, Explorer settings and Start menu settings. I believe you can install only one of them (I use both).

There is checkbox "Hide Search box" in Explorer settings, which hides Search box only in Explorer window.